# username regex pattern

Tags: python

This is my content

```
user(s): user-abc
test: data-1
```

I have tried the following regex to match user(s) but it appears to match both user(s) and test.

```
[A-Za-z_-][A-Za-z0-9_-]
```

The outcome should be:
`user-abc`

Comment: `[A-Za-z_-][A-Za-z]` is more than enough to get `user-abc`. what else you are trying to extract?

Comment: The expression will match two-character names only. Add `*` or `+`  to the second range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `user-abc` only where it is following `user(s):`  you can use a positive look behind;

`(?<=user\(s\): ).*`

This will match anything, of any length after `user(s):`

You can check this out on regex101 which provides an explanation and working example: [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/vpJHgH/1)